# Does Jquery add value to Java / Java EE programmer?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am a Java EE Programmer, I came across Jquery some where in Stack over flow, If I am Planning to learn Jquery

My question is 
1) Does Jquery Add any additional weightage in my Java / Java EE Career

2) If Yes, What way it can help me

3) Please share the links where I can learn Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Jquery Add any additional
>   weightage in my Java

jQuery is an **skill** and if you know this skill, it is always good and could come in handy any time in your career.

> If Yes, What way it can help me

The most obvious point at the moment coming in my mind is that of **Ajax** which becomes very very easy with jquery.

**See:**

**[Implementing Ajax in Java web application using JQuery](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2008/12/implementing-ajax-in-java-web-application-using-jquery/)**

.

Visit **[jQuery's site](http://jquery.com/)** to know more about it and its featues.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. It makes it much easier to write the client-side (JavaScript) part of AJAX applications, no matter what language the server-side part is written in.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Jquery Add any additional
>   weightage in my Java / Java EE Career

Java EE applications are more and more webapps, so client-side skills that can improve the user's experience are welcome.

> If Yes, What way it can help me

It greatly simplifies the manipulation of the DOM tree of the document, it deals with the differences between browsers, it provides simple-to-use ajax operations, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think that every new technology you learn adds value to your career, even if you don't need it directly. If you are working with HTML + CSS you should learn JavaScript and a JavaScript library like jQuery for sure or you will at some point not be able to catch up with current technologies anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that jQuery will help you if you never do anything with web front ends.  If you're 100% server-side, then there's little point in learning jQuery (arguments about "learning for its own sake is always good for you", the elegance of its design and implementation, prototype programming ideas aside).

If you do web UI work, it's hard to see how you can miss out on learning jQuery.  It's become *the* standard JavaScript library.  If you browse this site for very long, you'll see that lots of JavaScript questions are answered with "Use jQuery".

It reminds me of a quote from Louis Armstrong about jazz: "If you've gotta ask, you'll never know."  You shouldn't have to come to Stackoverflow to ask whether you should learn jQuery or not.